# Did Maupertuis ask how a particle knows to follow the path of stationary action?

Tags: theoretical-physics

I have read casual statements without reference suggesting that Maupertuis posed a question similar to Feynman's (in [this lecture, for instance](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_19.html)) as to how a particle "knows" to follow the path of stationary [but probably Maupertuis would have said least] action.  Does anyone know of a primary source where either Maupertuis or some other early proponent of action principles considered such a question?  Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maupertuis' consideration seems different...

See:

- Pierre Louis Maupertuis, [Accord de différentes loix de la nature qui avoient jusqu'ici paru incompatibles](https://books.google.it/books?id=cEdJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1) (1744):

> [page 12] *la Nature, dans la production de ses effets , agit toujours par les moyens les plus simples*. Si un corps doit aller d'un point à un autre sans rencontrer nul obstacle , ou s'il n'y doit aller qu'après avoir rencontré un obstacle invincible , la Nature l'y conduit par le chemin le plus court,
>   et par le temps le plus prompt.
>
> [page 15] *la lumiere se meut le plus vite dans les milieux les plus denses*
>
> [page 16] En méditant profondément sur cette matiere, j'ai pensé que la lumiere, lorsqu'elle passe d'un milieu dans un autre, abandonnant déjà le chemin le plus court, qui est celui de la ligne droite, pouvoit bien aussi ne pas suivre celui du temps le plus prompt. *En effet, quelle préférence devroit-il y avoir ici du temps sur l'espace ? la lumiere ne pouvant plus aller tout à la fois par le chemin le plus court , et par celui du temps le plus prompt,
>   pourquoi iroit-elle plutôt par l'un de ces chemins que par l'autre ?* [*emphasis added*]
>
> Aussi ne suit-elle aucun des deux: elle prend une route qui a un avantage plus réel: *le chemin qu'elle tient est celui par lequel la quantité d'action est la moindre*.
>
> [page 19] Tous les phénomenes de la réfraction s'accordent maintenant avec le
>   grand principe, que *la Nature, dans la production de ses effets, agit toujours par les voies les plus simples*. De ce principe suit, que *lorsque la lumiere passe d'un milieu dans un autre, le sinus de son angle de refraction est au sinus de son angle d'incidence en raison inverse des vitesses qu'a la lumiere dans chaque milieu*.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!  I agree, from these quotes it does not seem that Maupertuis is troubled by any question of how a localized particle would perform such a global optimization over paths.  He seems fine with ascribing the optimization to Nature as a kind of agent...

Comment: @Idempotent - Exactly; light does not know, simply because it obeys to a Law of Nature... presumably imposed by God, and he knows.